# Parallelize evaluation of points, storing points + output in list

Tags: evaluation, parallelization

I have a function which takes real numbers as inputs:

```
MyFunc:=[v1_,v2_,v3_,v4_]
```

and outputs a single real number. Now I want to evaluate `MyFunc` for many different combinations of input values of v1, v2, v3 and v4.

Let's assume my input values are:

```
v1 = {1,2.5,3,4}
v2 = {4,2}
v3 = {0.5,1}
v4 = {0.9,0.92,0.94}
```

Now I want to input each combination of the different values of the variables and input it in `MyFunc`. Then, for each set of input values I want to store them in a list, along with the output values.

So let's say `MyFunc[1,4,0.5,0.9]` outputs a value of 0.68, I want to store this in a list: {1,4,0.5,0.9,0.68}, where the first four values or the input values and the last value is the output value.

I know how to do this sequentially:

```
combinations = Tuples[{v1, v2, v3, v4}]
outputs = Flatten[MyFunc @@@ combinations];
```

And then I parse combinations and outputs

```
results = MapThread[Append, {"combinations", "outputs"}];
```

Now I have set up Mathematica on a server with 32 cores, so I would like to take advantage of this by parallelizing my task. I know how to parallelize things using Table, but it is important that the correct output is appended to the corresponding input values. Since things are happening on different Kernels, I have no clue how to parallelize my job producing the output results I want.

Comment: Note also that a very simple trick to "manage" matching input and output in general, is to either make `myFunc` return exactly that, instead of just a number, or to make a wrapper function `myFunc2[v1_,v2_,v3_,v4_] := {v1,v2,v3,v4,myFunc[v1,v2,v3,v4]}` and `Map` or `Table` that instead. That also saves you from the very costly `Append` thing you seem to be doing; `Append` has high complexity in Mathematica so one should avoid using it for long lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html).  Note that *Mathematica* preserves the order of the items return when using its `Parallel*` functions so you do not need to manage this. Se the [Parallel Computing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) guide.

With `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and `v4` as defined in the OP.

```
tups = Tuples[{v1, v2, v3, v4}];
```

No definition is given for `myFunc` so I use `Plus` here.

```
myFunc = Plus;
LaunchKernels[];
res = ParallelMap[{Sequence @@ ##, myFunc @@ ##} &, tups];
```

A quick look shows all is well.

```
res[[1 ;; 4]]
```

> ```
> {{1,4,0.5,0.9,6.4},{1,4,0.5,0.92,6.42},
>    {1,4,0.5,0.94,6.44},{1,4,1,0.9,6.9}}
> ```

`LaunchKernels` is not strictly needed as `ParallelMap` will launch but you have so many cores that I used it as a placeholder for any special setup you may have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use your approach, I get output results like
 >    {variables_input_values, -921.923 (0.0456039 + 0.797885 (3.08022 (0.0417715 + 0.262132 {0.4, 0.5} ))), so I think the function cannot handle the input in the way you have described above. MyFunc is the function callOR from the Kou model, with the original code taken from http://www.columbia.edu/~sk75/webcode.txt. Could you tell me how to adapt the input in order for the function callOR to produce a single output real number?

Comment: @PeterLawrence How have you loaded the `callOR` function? `myFunc @@ ##` replaces the `Head` of `List` on each list with `myFunc`. That is `{1,2}` becomes `myFunc[1, 2]`.

Comment: My bad, `callOR` produced weird results for a certain combination of input values. Everything works great, thanks for you help!

Comment: @PeterLawrence Have you see [`FinancialDerivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialDerivative.html) and the other functions in the [Financial Computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Finance.html) guide?

Comment: The strange thing is that for some combinations I get: 

Objects of unequal length in {15}
    {0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1}     cannot be combined. What could cause this error message? Tuples should be able to find all combinations right?

Comment: @PeterLawrence That sounds like you have missed a comma between items in your list of list in `Tuples`.